# Using lint-staged to check this commit is going to build ok?

Tags: git, husky, lint-staged, git-husky

When using husky and lint-staged is it possible to check what is staged builds in the pre-commit?

Kind of like this?

```
"lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,css,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "yarn build"
    ]
  }
```

If I try this I get a build error even if what is being committed should build, it says it could not find a 'pages' directory. Is this because it's trying to build literally only the staged files?

Maybe I'm trying to do something not possible. I'd just like to prevent code from being checked in which will fail on the CI build pipeline.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Here's my lint-staged.config.js file

```
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const prettierIgnorePath = path.resolve(__dirname, ".prettierignore");
const ignoredPatterns = fs
  .readFileSync(prettierIgnorePath, "utf-8")
  .split("\n");

function filterIgnoredFiles(filenames) {
  return filenames.filter((filename) => {
    return !ignoredPatterns.some((pattern) => filename.includes(pattern));
  });
}
module.exports = {
  // this will check Typescript files
  "**/*.(ts|tsx)": () => "npm run tsc -- --noEmit",


  "**/*.(ts|tsx|js)": (filenames) => {
    const filesToProcess = filterIgnoredFiles(filenames);
    const tasks = [`npm run eslint -- --fix ${filenames.join(" ")}`]; // eslint will always run on all files

    if (filesToProcess.length > 0) {
      tasks.push(`npm run prettier -- --write ${filesToProcess.join(" ")}`);
    }

    return tasks;
  },

  // this will Format MarkDown and JSON
  "**/*.(md|json)": (filenames) =>
    `npm run prettier -- --write ${filenames.join(" ")}`,
  //  build check here
  "**/*": () => "npm run build",
};
```

I'm working on a Nextjs Project and I run this via Husky Pre-commit hook.